# Query: HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn by mucking about with other peoples source code. I've got the following

```
 (http://codepen.io/mariusbalaj/pen/beALH)
```

I've tried so many things but can someone point me in the right direction of how when I click a button it display different info or page. Can I like it to a div or a new page.

```
<h2>Dont forget to check :active</h2>

<ul class="metro">

<li><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i><span>Games</span></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Settings</span></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Email</span></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i><span>Messages</span></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-music"></i><span>Music</span></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><span>Favorites</span></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i><span>Photos</span></li>

</ul>

<div class="box">
<span class="close"></span>
```

Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $box = $('.box');

$('.metro li').each(function(){
var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
var content = $(this).html();
$(this).click(function() {
$box.css('backgroundColor', color);
$box.addClass('open');
$box.find('p').html(content);
});

$('.close').click(function() {
$box.removeClass('open');
$box.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
});

});

});
```

Comment: Add the code here.

Comment: Done just done html and js

Comment: Did you add the JS link in the html ?

Comment: Add the scriept like this: <script src="myscripts.js"></script>

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: I have I've only put it like this to show the code

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to try answering "Can I **link** it to a div or a new page?":

Yes, by adding something like `<a href="..." target="_...">Random text</a>`.  To refer to a section/div in your HTML with an id 'Home', for example, then you can do this:
`<a href="#home">To Home</a>`.

As for your other question about displaying info when your mouse **is on top** of the button, then you could use fairly simple CSS to use the pseudo-element "div:hover" or "button:hover" just like you do for links on your page (body a:hover{...}).

Hope that answers your question(s).

Comment: Ah I meant click the button so when you click the button it morphs into the screen